# two button in struts inline with each other

Tags: java, html, css, jsp, struts2

as simple as it seems i have no idea how to put two buttons in line with each other especially since they have different functions.i have 1 form that logs in user with a log in button and a sign up button that lets user register. they are in two different form any idea on how to align the log in button to the sign up button here is an image of my log in

[image: align]

ang here is my code for log in jsp..can i align them with out using js or something else as much as possible i want to align them just by jsp..is there a way to do this

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>

<s:form action="login">
    <s:textfield label="email" key="email" name="email" size="20" />
    <s:password label="password" key="password" size="20" />
    <s:submit value="LogIn"/>     
</s:form>
<!--form method="post" ACTION="pagination.jsp">
<input type="submit" value="View">
</form-->

<s:form action="register.jsp">
    <s:submit value="SignUp" type="submit" float="right"/>     
</s:form>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT**

updating code from comments in here:

```
<s:form action="login" style="float:right"> 
  <s:textfield label="email" key="email" name="email" /> 
  <s:password label="password" key="password" /> 
  <s:submit value="LogIn"/> 
</s:form> 

<!--form method="post" ACTION="pagination.jsp"> 
<input type="submit" value="View"> 
</form--> 
<s:form action="register.jsp" style="float:right"> 
<s:submit value="SignUp" type="submit"/> 
</s:form>
```

UPDATE: is it possible to make it look like this ![enter image description here][2]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)No need of two forms, you can use [s:submit](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.0.x/docs/submit.html) and use `action` property.

2)To get two button on the same row you can use [s:form](http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/form.html) `theme` property

```
<s:form action="loginAction" theme="simple">
  <s:textfield label="email" key="email" name="email" size="20" /><br/>
  <s:password label="password" key="password" size="20" /><br/>
  <s:submit value="Register" name="registerBtn" />
  <s:submit value="LogIn" name="loginBtn"/>      
</s:form>
```

### Update

#### loginAction

```
String registerBtn = request.getParameter("registerBtn");
String loginBtn = request.getParameter("loginBtn");

//if registerBtn is clicked then it's value Register is get stored in registerBtn.
//if not registerBtn is not clicked then variable registerBtn has null.
if(registerBtn != null)
{
  //return and call action for register.jsp
}
if(loginBtn != null)
{
  //do the login code here
}
```

To use `request` object you need to implement `ServletRequestAware` interface and override `setServletRequest` method

```
public class LoginAction  implements ServletRequestAware
{
   HttpServletRequest request;
   public void setServletRequest(HttpServletRequest arg0) 
   {
      this.request = arg0;      
   }

   //rest of the above updated code here
}
```

Comment: i have achieve the look that i want but i sacrificed functionality register button not working anymore its functions is like the function of log in button..code is great this is what im looking perfect fit mate ahahahaha but i think i can fix this

Comment: actually i can make the register button work its function is not what i want it to be its function is that of the log in button but the UI is perfect the only problem is that the function is not the same anymore i think the form is needed what do you think?

Comment: im trying it..it looks like this see my version of you code <s:form action="login">
  <s:textfield label="email" key="email" name="email" size="20" /><br/>
  <s:password label="password" key="password" size="20" /><br/>
  <s:submit action="register.jsp" name="register" value="Register"/>
  <s:submit value="LogIn"/>      
</s:form> when i click register the function is like the function of login i dont know where i got it wrong can you check it?

Comment: @satinekianne : updated answer. Please see. If you have any question let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Yes you can remove that but then you will not have two buttons on same row. My advice is you can create [HTML table](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_table.asp) , put two buttons in two `td` and use simple html tags to create form.

Comment: @arnakit what import do i need for request in request.getParameter("loginBtn");?

Comment: @arnakit sorry cant figure out how to make it work if you can make it a bit clearer then maybe i can make it work i really tried but i cant make it work i dont even know where to put it i tried it in jsp i think it is suppose to be in jsp but i cant make it work if you can give me a sample it will be appreciated

Comment: sir i tried your code but its just too complicated for me this is how i implemented it but i cant figure out how ti fix this one http://pastebin.com/ndY5WQ6s

Comment: it was great perfect! 1 more question what are other ways to validate if user and password is empty im using this  public void validate() {

  if (StringUtils.isEmpty(getEmail())) {
   //email blank
   addFieldError("email", "email is empty");
  }
  if (StringUtils.isEmpty(getPassword())) {
   //email password
   addFieldError("password", "password is empty");
  }
 } but it wont work

Answer (score 0):

Remove `float` from Signup button and instead apply it on `form` field and it should work.... [see a basic demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/8Brhx/2/)

**Also**, add the `float` properties to both the form fields and not only one....

**EDIT**

This will save your time

```
<form action="login" style="float:right; "> 
    <input type="textfield" label="email" key="email" name="email" /> <br />
  <input type="password" label="password" key="password" /> <br />
  <input type="submit" value="LogIn" style="float:right;"/> <br />
<form> 

<!--form method="post" ACTION="pagination.jsp"> 
<input type="submit" value="View"> 
</form--> 
<form action="register.jsp"> 
<input type="submit" value="SignUp" type="submit" style="float:right;margin-top:-20px;"/> 
<form>
```

[**see demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/gH7qM/1/)

Comment: is turned a bit it looks like this signup button inline inline with email below it the password and below it the log in button all of them at the right of the screen..here is my code <s:form action="login" style="float:right">
    <s:textfield label="email" key="email" name="email" />
    <s:password label="password" key="password" />
    <s:submit value="LogIn"/>     
</s:form>
<!--form method="post" ACTION="pagination.jsp">
<input type="submit" value="View">
</form-->

<s:form action="register.jsp" style="float:right">
    <s:submit value="SignUp" type="submit"/>     
</s:form>

Comment: how exactly you want buttons to align???m not able to understand...this is the current output => http://jsfiddle.net/gH7qM/

Comment: i saw your fiddle it looks good i updated an image to show you how i want it i have no more idea i tried your way but it wont work

Comment: @satinekianne : done...please see the edit, `margin-top` was the trick here :)

Comment: i tried it but im going on the top most wait il try it again il come back on you on this

Comment: just play with `margin-top:-20px;` depending on your other css...and that will do the trick for u! :)

Comment: i see did you put other css that is why icant make it work ive been wondering why it wont work coz it is perfect in fiddle and in my code its no so it depends on the number in margin okokok this one is the better solution mate

Comment: happy new year and happy coding

Answer (score 0):

it isnt really the best solution but so far i was able to get a work around on my problem it looks nice and the functions are ok i just added css on the buttons to make it look good 
[image]

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>  
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
<s:form action="login">
    <s:textfield label="email" key="email" name="email" size="20" />
    <s:password label="password" key="password" size="20" />
    <s:submit value="LogIn" style="float:left;"/>     
</s:form>
<s:form action="register.jsp">
    <s:submit value="SignUp" type="submit" style="float:right;margin-top:-5px;"/>     
</s:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

resolve like below one with div tag another with td and div both enclosed in a td and then tr working fine

```
<tr>
                <td class="pageHeader">
                <div class="formButton"><input type="submit" value="Login" name="loginActionForm.loginButton" class="btncolor"/>
</div>
                    <td>
<div class="formButton"><input type="reset" name="loginActionForm.clearButton" value="Clear" class="btncolor" onfocus="document.forms[0].user.focus()"/>
</div></td>
                    </td>

        </tr>
```

Comment: Please put more explanation of your answer with illustrations to make it more clear

Comment: I've put your code in a code block (because you can't just paste HTML code in your answer). Now please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45839719/edit) it and give it a clean formatting. Thanks.